# Algorithm - Lexicographically largest possible magical substring

Tags: java, algorithm

I am working on this [magical sub-string problem](https://www.careercup.com/question?id=5700340897808384).

> Magical binary strings are non-empty binary strings if the following two conditions are true:
>
> - The number of 0's is equal to the number of 1's.
> - For every prefix of the binary string, the number of 1's should not be less than the number of 0's.

I got stuck on how to proceed further in my Java program.

Here is my program:

```
static String findLargest(String str) {
        String[] splits = str.split("");
        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
            if (splits[i].equals("0")) {
                continue;
            }
            int zeros = 0;
            int ones = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            for (int j = i; j < splits.length; j++) {               
                if (splits[j].equals("0")) {
                    zeros++;
                } else {
                    ones++;
                }
                sb.append(splits[j]);
                if (zeros == ones && ones >= zeros) {
                    set.add(sb.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        set.remove(str);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set);
        System.out.println(list);

        return null;
    }
```

Using this program I am able to get the magical sub-strings for the given input String `11011000` as `[10, 101100, 1100]` in my `list` variable.

Now from here I am struggling how to remove the invalid entry of `101100` from my list and then use the elements `10, 1100` to swap from my input `11011000` to get the final result as `11100100`

Also please guide me if there is any other alternate approach.

Comment: @Dukeling, I tried to copy the question from the link which I mentioned in my post, but it is not allowing me to do it, so added the link to the question

Comment: @Dukeling, I added an update with details from above link, please check.

Comment: Note that these are Dyck words (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language)). That is, they're words of balanced parentheses. Replace all the 1's with "(" and all the 0's with ")" to see it. Making it as lexicographically large as possible while retaining its "meaning" basically means sorting each sequence of consecutive "groups" in a decreasing order of depth (recursively). If you try to think of it that way you might get a better idea on how to do it. =)

Comment: @TomerGodinger, Thanks for the hint, can you please explain more on what is `sorting each sequence of consecutive "groups" in a decreasing order of depth (recursively)` with an example

Comment: "()()()" [i.e. 101010] - I think of this as three consecutive groups of depth 1. "((()))" would be one group of depth 3. "(())()" has two groups, one of depth 2 and one of depth 1. In "( () (()) () ) (((())))" [I've added spaces for readability] there are two groups: the first is of depth 3 and the second is of depth 4. If you sort the outermost sequence by decreasing depth you'll get "(((()))) ( () (()) () )". Then recursively sort each group. The first one stays the same, but the second one has in it groups of depth 1, 2, 1 so it becomes "( (()) () () )". Result: "(((()))) ( (()) () () )"

Comment: You could state your problem better - the string 101100 is a magical substring - the number of 0 and 1s is equal and for each prefix, the number of 1s is equal or larger than the number of 0. If the issue is that it is also overlapping the other substrings, we could avoid it by deciding that for each found magical substring we eliminate other substrings that contain it. But that means that for one magical string there could be a few different sets of magical substrings which do not overlap within the set.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about only eliminating the unwanted "101100" from the result, here is the answer

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        findLargest("11011000");
     }
     public static String findLargest(String str) {
        String[] splits = str.split("");
        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
            if (splits[i].equals("0")) {
                continue;
            }
            int zeros = 0;
            int ones = 0;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            for (int j = i; j < splits.length; j++) {               
                if (splits[j].equals("0")) {
                    zeros++;
                } else {
                    ones++;
                }
                sb.append(splits[j]);
                if (zeros == ones && ones >= zeros) {
                    set.add(sb.toString());
                    j = i +1; // RESET THE INDEX ELEMENT TO SKIP THE SUBSTRING FROM CONSIDERATION
                    break;  // BREAK FROM THE LOOP
                }
            }
        }
        set.remove(str);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set);
        System.out.println(list);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: "If your question is about only eliminating the unwanted "101100" from the result" - no, the problem is significantly harder than that.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide some points.
First, get all the magical substrings and store them as a pair of start and end index(l, r) in a list;
Second, sort the list based on index l;
Those who can be potentially swapped substring can get from the same index l. look at the example given "11011000"
the list will have (0,7),(1,2),(1,6),(3,6),(4,5)
obviously only potential swap is among (1,2)(1,6)

deal these substrings have same index l will help find potential swapping substrings, sort them to find the maximum order.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Pair{
         int start;
         int end;
     }
    
     
    public  List<Pair> findmagicalPairs(String binString){
        List<Pair> magicPairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();
        for(int start=0;start<binString.length()-1;start++){
            int ones=0;
            int zeros=0;
            for(int i=start; i<binString.length();i++){
                if(binString.charAt(i) == '1'){
                    ones++;
                } else if(binString.charAt(i)=='0'){
                    zeros++;
                }
                
                if(ones == zeros){ //check if magical
                    Pair temp=new Pair();
                    temp.start=start;
                    temp.end =i;
                    magicPairs.add(temp);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return magicPairs;
        
    } 

    public  String largestMagical(String binString) {
    // Write your code here
    List<Pair> allPairs = findmagicalPairs(binString);
    String largest=binString;
    //check by swapping each pairs    
    for(int i=0;i<allPairs.size()-1;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<allPairs.size()-1;j++){
            if(allPairs.get(i).end+1 == allPairs.get(j).start){
                //consecutive Pair so swap and see largest
                int index = allPairs.get(j).start;
                String swapped = binString.substring(0,allPairs.get(i).start)+binString.substring(allPairs.get(j).start,allPairs.get(j).end+1)+binString.substring(allPairs.get(i).start,allPairs.get(i).end+1)+binString.substring(allPairs.get(j).end+1);
                largest = LargestString(largest, swapped);
            } else {
                //else ignore
            }
        }
    }
    
    return largest;
    
    }


    public  String LargestString(String first, String second){
        if(first.compareTo(second)>0){
            return first;
        } else {
            return second;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Code!

```
const largestMagical = (binString) => {
  //console.log({ binString });
  const len = binString.length;
  const height = Array(len + 1).fill(0),
    num = { 1: 1, 0: -1 },
    marked = Array(len + 1).fill(false),
    sameHeights = {};
  let i,
    j,
    result = "";
  for (i = 1; i <= len; ++i) {
    height[i] = height[i - 1] + num[binString[i - 1]];
  }

  //console.log({ height });
  for (i = 0; i <= len; ++i) {
    if (marked[i]) continue;
    marked[i] = true;
    sameHeights[i] = [i];
    for (j = i + 1; j <= len; ++j) {
      if (height[j] < height[i]) break;
      if (height[j] === height[i]) {
        sameHeights[i].push(j);
        marked[j] = true;
      }
    }
  }

   //console.log({ sameHeights });

  for (let k in sameHeights) {
    const leng = sameHeights[k].length;
    let startId, midId, endId;
    for (startId = 0; startId < leng - 2; ++startId) {
      for (midId = startId + 1; midId < leng - 1; ++midId) {
        for (endId = midId + 1; endId < leng; ++endId) {
          const start = sameHeights[k][startId],
            mid = sameHeights[k][midId],
            end = sameHeights[k][endId];
            //console.log({start, mid, end});
          const swapped =
            binString.substring(0, start) +
            binString.substring(mid, end) +
            binString.substring(start, mid) +
            binString.substring(end, len);
            //console.log({swapped});
          if (swapped > result) result = swapped;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
};

console.log(largestMagical("1010111000"));
console.log(largestMagical("11011000"));
```